# How can I add a glow to a tv screen without ruining the video playing on it?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, video, effects

I am producing an animation where there is a tv set playing an episode from the Twilight Zone series.

As you can see on the picture, the image on the screen is crisp and clear, but as I will dim the light in the room, I need to have a glow coming from the screen.

I have tried to use an emission shader for the screen, a point light in front of it, a cube as projector, but all these solutions are ruining the image, rendering it grey or even totally white.

What do you suggest I could do to have the screen glowing and keep video that is playing looking good?

[image]

Comment: sorry I could not get the image loading.. I must have a wrong link..  if you can confirm what link to use for loading an image or video?  Thanks

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Light Path node..  that's it.  I knew there should be a way but I missed it.  Thank you for the answer..